# How to display image from MySQL in Intel-xdk using php

Tags: php, mysql, intel-xdk

How to display image from MySQL in Intel-xdk using php. Please how can i display image in Intel xdk using ajax request? 
I have tried to retrieve an information which only displays the text and not the images.
I use php and when i request the information only the text is being displayed.
Here is the code i used to retrieve the data

```
   function showUser() {

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = this.responsetext;

                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/SaltCity/index.php",true);
                xmlhttp.send()  
            }
```

Comment: please share some code...

Comment: Please i have added the code i used to retrieve the information

Comment: Are you downloading mixed content? If you're downloading an image as text, you have to encode your response using base64 and then display it that way. If you're downloading html, then you just need to render it as html and check that all links are properly referenced.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: I am new, can you help me with the code please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's the PHP to return a filename in JSON. This assumes that you store the filename in MySQL in a field called profileimage and the name of your php is getprofileimage.php.

```
$result = $conn->query("select profileimage from profiles where userid = '" . $userid . "'");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"profileimage":"' . $rs["profileimage"] . '"}';
}
$outp .="]";
```

When run, this returns a JSON string like this

```
[{
    "profileimage": "abcd.jpg"
}]
```

In JavaScript, do this:

```
function getProfile(){
    var url = "http://yourserverlocation.com" + "/getprofileimage.php";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: JSONObject,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (arr) {
            _getProfileResult(arr);
        },
        error: function () {
            validationMsg();
        }
    });
}

function _getProfileResult(arr){
    profileimage = arr[0].profileimage;
    //assuming that you have a <img id="imgProfilePicture> tag
    $("#imgProfilePicture").attr("src","http://yourserverlocation.com/" + "/images/" + profileimage +"_s");     
}
```

Comment: Am storing just the filename, Please i need help urgently. Thank you in advance